# Error importing lxml package python in Ubuntu

Tags: python

When I try importing lxml package in python I am receiving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in    <module>
   from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol:   PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1
```

(Python version ->2.7.5)

Comment: See [ubuntu 11.04 lxml import etree problem for custom python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806831/ubuntu-11-04-lxml-import-etree-problem-for-custom-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can be compiled in two different *modes*; UCS2 or UCS4 – see [How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1446347/95735) question at Stackoverflow. All binary packages (like lxml) must be compiled in the same mode that Python was compiled in. It looks like your lxml was compiled in UCS4 mode while Python was compiled in UCS2 mode. You have to recompile one of them so that they use the same mode.