# How to resolve 'ImportError' in Python?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, pip

Have installed required module `lxml` but when imported, errors `ImportError: No module named lxml`

How do I know

1. From which location python modules are being considered?
2. Which python version and pip is in use or set ?

Please help me to understand and resolve this issue.

```
uname -a
Linux machine-name 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

which python
/usr/local/bin/python

which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

pip --version
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

python
Python 2.7.16 (default, May  6 2020, 13:05:58) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import urllib2
>>> os.path.abspath(urllib2.__file__)
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc'

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

echo $PYTHONPATH
doesn't display anything (empty)


ls -ls /usr/bin/python*

   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9  /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16  /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9  /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16  /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
3264 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3341288  /usr/bin/python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33  /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9  /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4
3628 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3714088  /usr/bin/python3.4
3628 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3714088  /usr/bin/python3.4m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10  /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.4m
   
ls -ls /usr/local/bin/python*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9  /usr/local/bin/python -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14  /usr/local/bin/python-config -> python2-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7  /usr/local/bin/python.orig -> python2
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9  /usr/local/bin/python2 -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16  /usr/local/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
8280 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8478000  /usr/local/bin/python2.7
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1687  /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config

find /bin /usr /lib* /home -type f -name "pip*" -executable
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip2.7
/usr/local/bin/pip2
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip2

/usr/bin/pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

/usr/bin/pip2 install lxml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

/usr/local/bin/pip2 install lxml
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)

/usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install lxml
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)

/usr/local/bin/pip install lxml
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)

sudo pip install lxml
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
The directory '/home/abcd/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/abcd/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)

python -m pip install lxml
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip

python
Python 2.7.16 (default, May  6 2020, 13:05:58) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml

import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))

/usr/local/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Try installing lxml with `python -m pip install lxml`. Using this method should guarantee that lxml is installed in a way where the python you see from `which python` can use it. (Disclaimer I'm not 100% sure about this with python 2.7)

Comment: @ToxicGLaDOS Thanks for responding. I had tried that earlier but errors as python -m pip install lxml
"/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip"

Comment: If you don't have a requirement on python 2.7 I would recommend using python 3. If you go this route remember that you often need to specify python3 and pip3 explicitly. So you might have success with `python3 -m pip install lxml` after you install python3 and pip3 through your package manager.

Comment: @ToxicGLaDOS understand. But currently need to continue on Python2.7. I am trying very hard to understand this python and pip-install-modules association, but seems to be confusing. I believe that's not tough. It would be great if you can help me to crack/understand this.

Comment: @ToxicGLaDOS I couldn't make out where I am going wrong or If I am missing something here. I believe I have provided all possible info, so that helps anyone to analyse and debug.

Comment: @ToxicGLaDOS Can you please help me ?

Comment: It's really hard to say. Python is [somewhat notorious](https://xkcd.com/1987/) for having these problems. Here's some sanity checks though. Make sure you have pip and python installed the same way. This probably means through apt, so `sudo apt-get install python` and `sudo apt-get install python-pip` on ubuntu. Try updating pip in your package manager. Try using the --user flag in pip to install the package, so `pip install --user lxml`. If that all fails, I'd try uninstalling python and pip with your package manager and reinstalling them (or possibly doing some force reinstall).

Comment: On the Python prompt, could you `>>> import sys`, then `>>> sys.path`? The `dist-packages/` subdirectory where `pip` installs `lxml` is not a standard Python installation directory as far as I'm aware, and probably a Debian/Ubuntu thing (I've seen this before). It looks like Python doesn't pick up this specific directory, perhaps because `/usr/local/` indicates the used Python is not the system Python (and thus not configured to use this directory). `sys.path` should reveal whether this directory is read by Python.

Comment: Also: is your `lxml` installation to be used system-wide, by multiple users, or just one user (that is, yourself)?

Comment: @ToxicGLaDOS Edited and added sys.path above, and lxml to be used system-wide.

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)`, hmm, on my machine lxml gets installed in in `site-packages`: `Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/ja/.local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (4.6.3)`. Add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to PYTHONPATH or move lxml to site-packages.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk How does pip understand the path. where modules to be installed ? As you mentioned /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages , how does pip know to install modules here ?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk echo $PYTHONPATH displays nothing (empty)

Comment: `dist-packages` is Debian specific extension, I cannot say that I know and want to know why it was introduced

Comment: 0 0 != ToxicGLaDOS, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

To make Python find the installed package(s) system-wide, do the following:

In the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory, make a file called `distpackages.pth` (or any file that has a `.pth` extension; I choose an obvious name, while avoiding the hyphen).

Inside that file, create one line:

```
../dist-packages
```

That's it. That line refers to the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` directory that `pip` is set up to install things in. Python will read this file and add the line(s) in it to `sys.path`, and then knows where to find the installed package(s).

The explanation for this is in the [Python site documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html). And this answer is essentially a copy of [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/247649).

---

I don't know why and how `pip` is configured to install things in a different place than usual. This is an Ubuntu (or Debian) thing I've seen before, but it's rather odd to see it for just `pip`, but not `python`. Plus I wouldn't expect it for something that was installed in `/usr/local`, which are mostly (later) user installations.

Comment: `Python 2.7.16 (default, May  6 2020, 13:05:58) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml

>>> from lxml import etree

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1
>>>`

Comment: Followed as you mentioned, `import lxml` didn't give any error. But `from lxml import etree` errored as `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1`

Comment: Looks like built with --enable-unicode=ucs2, not sure.
`>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160386/error-importing-lxml-package-python-in-ubuntu

Comment: How can we resolve this ?

Comment: @stack This is a different error: it has little to nothing to do with your initial installation problem.

Comment: @stack From your linked Q&A regarding this issue, it looks like the PyPI version of lxml was compiled with UCS4, while your Python installation was compiled with UCS2. You'll have to manually download the lxml source and install it. An alternative is to re-install `/usr/local/bin/python`, build with UCS4 this time. To check your current build, try `/usr/local/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print sys.maxunicode"`. Getting `65535` likely indicates a UCS2 Python build.

Comment: Yes, it's UCS2. If to be installed 'lxml' manually, in which path should it be installed ?

Comment: @stack `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` should do the job for you. The setup.py script will get all the necessary information from Python itself. It will probably install it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (possibly the `dist-packages` subdir instead, but unlikely).

Comment: Tried as you said but still results in ERROR (from lxml import etree), ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1

Comment: Check what `python setup.py install` shows: it should tell you where the package is installed. Perhaps it picks another subdirectory, one that is later on the PYTHONPATH and thus not picked up.

Comment: Also, uninstall the UCS4 lxml version that you got from PyPI first: `pip uninstall lxml`. Then install your own compiled package, as above.